# Access variable on child from parent in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to get access to a variable "Name" in my child class from my parent class. I am using react routers on this project. I've been using React for a few days, so I am open to any suggestions or refactoring.

Child class:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return (
       <ul className="list">
            {this.props.business.map(function(business, i) {
                    let Name = Object.keys(business).length - 1;
                    return (
                        <li key={business.id}>
                            <Link to="/" className="inner">
                                <div className="li-img">
                                    <img src={business.image} alt="Image Alt Text" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="li-text">
                                    <h4 className="li-head">{business.name}</h4>
                                    <p className="li-sub">Summary of content</p>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                       </li>
                    );
                })}
        </ul>
    )
}
});
```

Parent Class:

```
import React from 'react';
import Business from './businesses';
import { getBusiness } from 'api/global';

export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        business: [],
    }
},
  componentWillMount: function() {
      var _this = this;
       getBusiness().then(function(response) {
          _this.setState({
            business: response.data
        })
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
},

  render: function() {
    return (
        <Business business={this.state.business} text={Name} />
    )
   }
});
```

Comment: Just as an aside, `Name` seems like a strange name for variable containing a number.

Comment: @greenasjade - Good catch. Was using a string before and forgot to change back...

Comment: Its difficult to understand your question but won't  `this.props.text` get you access to the variable name in the child class.

Comment: @shubham - I am looking to access a variable inside child from the parent.

Comment: @user992731 But why?   Your example doesn't show us why you want to do this.   At the moment, you are accessing `Name` defined in the child - but the only thing you're doing is passing it on the text prop back to the child.  What is the point of that?

Comment: Ah, right. Yes, that is my bad

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do, directly, what you are attempting here.

At the time that you render `Business` you need to know the values that you want to pass to it.   Your "construct" is just like asking "I want to pass a parameter to a function that is calculated by the function that I am calling".

[Communication between components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) gives you a hint at what is needed: some event that causes a re-render after the new value (`Name`) has been computed.

This could be by the Business updating a state variable `Name`, which would cause a re-render, or by passing in a callback (as the example shows).

Comment: Afterthought: actually, why does the parent need `Name` at all, if the only thing it is doing is passing it to the child.  AND ... you don't appear to be using the resulting `text` prop in the child at all.   My answer is still true, as far as I know, but I agree with the commenter that it is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve!